# error: error in 'egg_base' option: 'src' does not exist or is not a directory

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, src

I'm trying to install Python packaging tools in Pycharm CE Ubuntu 18.04 and this error occurs.

Excuted command:
`/tmp/tmpl3kyfibgpycharm-management/pip-10.0.1/setup.py install`

Error ocurred: `error: error in 'egg_base' option: 'src' does not exist or is not a directory`

Command output:

```
running install
running bdist_egg
error: error in 'egg_base' option: 'src' does not exist or is not a directory
```

I also tried `pip install src`and this does not work either.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

For python 3 you must install it using

`sudo apt-get install python3-pip`

it will work for python 2.7

`sudo apt-get install python-pip`

Comment: but isn't the question related with `egg_base`: `src` is not found? Please explain how and why your solution works?

Comment: Yes you are right,  the question header is egg_base:src but the question is related to the Pycharm CE and it is related to python. That's why  the solution works

Comment: Ohh okay, so pip itself is not being installed or not working correctly in the questioner's system. correct, Understood. thank you for the comment back!

Answer (score 2):

When choose the route of Project Interpreter, you'd better select the route `'/usr/bin/python3'` instead of `'/usr/bin/python3.6'`.

Answer (score 2):

I got similar problem when running setup.py by jython from outside of setup.py folder (just like your case). 
I don't know the root cause but when you change folder to where setup.py and scr folder is, installation completes.

```
cd /tmp/tmpl3kyfibgpycharm-management/pip-10.0.1
python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your interpreter to (VENV) instead of User

Answer (score 1):

Just changed my interpreter to VENV (a virtual one) as user11507396 stated and it worked. If you are using PyCharm, you can do it as follows:

1. Go to Settings -> Project Interpreter -> Add
   [image: List item]
2. Choose whatever you need. In my case choosing python3 as the base interpreter solved the question issue.
   [image]